# IllegalStateException: No request is currently active when Trying to get IP address and Host

Tags: java, quarkus

I'm trying to retrieve a source's IP and hostname for logging purposes.

I've created a bean that gets has an object of both HttpServletRequest ServletContext. I have functions that get the user's remote IP address and remote hostname.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

@RequestScoped
public class RequestDetailsConfig {

  private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
  private ServletContext context;

  public RequestDetailsConfig(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @Context ServletContext contx) {
    this.httpRequest = req;
    this.context = contx;
  }

  public void setHttpRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.httpRequest = request;
  }

  public HttpServletRequest getHttpRequest() {
    return this.httpRequest;
  }

  public String getRemoteAddress() {
    return httpRequest.getRemoteAddr();
  }

  public String getRemoteHost() {
    return httpRequest.getRemoteHost();
  }
}
```

I have another bean that is used as my "log creator" and "log producer".

```
@Singleton
public class ProducerConfig {

  @Inject
  private RequestDetailsConfig requ;

  // Create producer and other helper functions

  // Making log which uses RequestDetailsConfig.getRemoteAddr() and getRemoteHost()
  public NessLog makeViewingDashboardLog() {
    ...setters
    .setSourceHostIp4(requ.getRemoteAddress())
    .setSourceHostHostname(requ.getRemoteHost())
    .buildLog();
  }
}
```

I then have a class that overrides my filter to set my HttpServletRequest object

```
public class HttpRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

  @Inject
  private RequestDetailsConfig requestDetails;

  @Context
  HttpServletRequest request;

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(containerRequestContext.getRequest());
    requestDetails.setHttpRequest(request);
  }
}
```

When I run my application and land on the page that sends out a request to retrieve data I get back the following error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000048: No request is currently active
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletRequestContext.requireCurrent(ServletRequestContext.java:84)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.ServletProducer.request(ServletProducer.java:18)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.ServletProducer_Subclass.request$$superaccessor3(ServletProducer_Subclass.zig:451)
```

I'm hoping someone may have some insight on helping me resolve this issue.

Comment: You can't inject `@Context` objects into regular CDI beans like `RequestDetailsConfig`. `@Context` only works in JAX-RS classes

Comment: I see, ok, so let me scale back a little. I may be overcomplicating it. What is a simple approach to get a user's remote IP address and hostname in Quarkus?

Comment: Also worth noting, this is using GraphQL endpoints